# How to capture video and audio from /dev/videoX?

Tags: video

I have connected a Pinnacle Dazzle to my Fedora workstation and the system has correctly identified it and created `/dev/video2` and an audio device (that I see in my audio settings).

I want to use this to capture some old VHS tapes and I can use `tvtime` to see the video (not the audio though). But how can I capture the video and audio streams into a video file?

I tried to find tools for this, but all I could find was video editors, not capturers.

Comment: The Dazzle should appear as an ALSA audio source. However, its volume control is available via v4l2. You may need to explicitly select the video source and un-mute the audio via `v4l2-ctl --set-standard=pal --set-input=0 --set-ctrl=mute=0`. Have you done that? Afterwards, you should be able to use any software to mux the audio and video streams such as ffmpeg (with multiple `-i` and `-map` options). Be aware: A/V synchronization may imperfect. Only with hardware muxers I achieved perfect results.

Comment: @Hermann I haven't tried that, but I will.